# compare a column from one table to another table and list the matching second table rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange issue.
I need to compare a column A from table 1 to a column B in table 2.
If the value match, then list the column A from table 1 and its matching rows from table 2
Please help with SQL statement.

I see duplicates in that column from both tables. Table 1 has 3850 records and table 2 has 750 records inclusive of duplicates. Due to the duplicates, the join queries are bringing hundred thousands of rows. I need the exact 3850 rows in result and matching rows from table 2. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Join..

```
SELECT table1.A FROM tableA JOIN table2 ON table1.A = table2.B
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this isn't strange at all; it's just a join:

```
select
    t1.columnA
    , t2.*
from
    table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t2.columnB = t1.columnA
```

Comment: I see duplicates in that column from both tables.
Table 1 has 3850 records and table 2 has 750 records inclusive of duplicates.
Due to the duplicates, the join queries are bringing hundred thousands of rows.
I need the exact 3850 rows in result and matching rows from table 2.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OR even simpler way would be

```
SELECT Colum1 FROM TABLE1
INTERSECT
SELECT Colum2 FROM TABLE2
```